# AWS Opsworks where to put data_bag folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, databags

I am using AWS Opsworks with Chef 12 and custom cookbooks. I would like to use data_bags also, but I can't figure out where Opsworks looks for them.

If I add them the /var/chef/data_bags I can successfully run the recipes using `chef-client --local-mode`, However when I try via the Opsworks -> Stack -> Execute recipe I get the follow error.

```
[2016-01-07T21:05:07+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/data/users
```

It seems that OpsWorks creates its own data_bags at this location `/var/chef/runs/9586fca2-52d1-43a8-9b3c-6fc0e4e79259/data_bags` However these are all custom AWS folders eg..

```
aws_opsworks_app      aws_opsworks_ecs_cluster            aws_opsworks_instance  aws_opsworks_rds_db_instance  aws_opsworks_user
aws_opsworks_command  aws_opsworks_elastic_load_balancer  aws_opsworks_layer     aws_opsworks_stack
```

How can I either add to the OpsWorks Databag or where do I place my own data_bag folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-server-migrate.html#best-practices-server-migrate-data-bags

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11-10.html#workingcookbook-chef11-10-databag

So basically you need to define, inside opsworks custom jsons that you attach to the stack level or layer level, etc. Those jsons are picked up and injected in the databags that end up being part of a run. (i.e. you cannot define the bags inside of cookbooks)

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks for that. One question though. Where does that json file live? The root of the cookbook?

Comment: it's a config of the opsworks stack. you can inspect/alter it it via the api or by using the was console. (i.e. it's not a file)

Comment: AHhhhh.. that custom JSON box. Got it. Thanks for that.